# Max value of Android Step Counter Sensor

Tags: android, android-sensors

I would like to know what exactly happens when `event.values[0]` of TYPE_STEP_COUNTER reaches its maximum value? Does it reset to 0 or just stop counting?

PS. Documentation does not say anything about this. It says it only resets to 0 when the phone is rebooted.

Comment: The TYPE_STEP_COUNTER is an int, so its max value will be 2147483647. I honestly do not know what will happen then. The real question is how are you going to measure 2147483647 steps?

Comment: Ok thanks, I did not know it is a very large number.